# insert <div> in one instance of php loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, while-loop

The content on the main page of my site is displayed in a box that has the article on the left and other articles in that category in a list on the right.  The wordpress main page index is set to create another box immediately underneath the first and so on, for each category I wish to have displayed.

I would like to insert a small div section for video thumbnails after the first content box, then allow wordpress to go back to posting the other content boxes below that.  I am just learning php and have been having trouble with this.

I have added the div, in the appropriate position in the loop, but how can i isolate it to appear only under the first content box ($cat1), rather than all content boxes?

I tried

```
<?php while($cat1);{
echo '<div id="video"></div>'}
?>
```

but im just not sure, 
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just set up a simple counter to handle this, as you know which iteration of the loop you have to add the video section in - the first.

Before the loop initialise a variable as the counter, set it to zero.  In your loop you check if the counter is zero, if so you insert your video code.  Then you add 1 to the counter and the video won't be displayed again.

```
<?php $count = 0 ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    // Your normal loop stuff here

    <?php
    if ($count == 0 ) {

        echo '<div id="video"></div>';

    }

    $count++;
    ?>

<?php endwhile; endif: ?>
```

Comment: No problem at all.  Good luck with the PHP - just reading questions and answers on Stackoverflow will help you a lot, that's my tip :)